# What happened to my flair?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, combined-flair

I have some SE flair badge on my blog, one piece of SO flair, and one global SE. I noticed today that my global SE badge had transmogrified into Area51 flair. What's going on here?

[image]

Note: it still links to my SE global profile.

Also note: Flair is displayed incorrectly *on [my SE flair page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/150214/fredley/flair)!*

Comment: Try to refresh now, do you still get the issue?

Comment: @NickCraver Yes

Comment: @NickCraver 24 hours later, still a problem

Comment: @NickCraver While I see fredley's flair right, [my one is wrong now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130602/the-combined-flair-does-show-only-my-area-51-account).

Comment: Mine is back now, didn't make a note of exactly when it went back though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All non-Area-51 flair data currently comes from [the public API](https://api.stackexchange.com/). In fact, [this is the query](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/associated-users#page=1&pagesize=100&ids=35162&filter=!0RYZZ%2867AC8AWD9D&run=true).

There seems to have been a momentary hiccup in the API at the time your flair was cached, leaving only your Area 51 profile info in the flair.

We'll improve the logic here, e.g. stop caching bad data. Sorry for the inconvenience.