# The combined flair does show only my Area 51 account

Tags: bug, flair, combined-flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to my flair?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129520/what-happened-to-my-flair)

So I just had the idea to print out my combined Stack Exchange flair for the Stack Overflow Meetup day ... and this is what I see:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dY8Y.png]

Here is the live copy-paste link, it looks for me just same:

[image: profile for Paŭlo Ebermann on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

The interesting part is, if I use the image-upload dialog and input the URL from the HTML above, it looks right:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuKLg.png]

So I suppose there are some problems with the content delivery network, it shows the wrong image to me, and the right image to imgur. This should be fixed.

One more observation: If I append `?theme=clean` (but not `?theme=default`), I get a good image, showing all my accounts, too.

Here are the HTTP headers I get (without being logged in):

```
$ httpclient https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/295869.png | head
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Content-Type: image/png
Expires: Wed, 27 Jun 2012 11:22:09 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 28 Apr 2012 11:22:09 GMT
Date: Sat, 28 Apr 2012 13:31:39 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 9335

�PNG
```

This smaller file is the one with only my Area51-account.

```
$ httpclient 'https://stackexchange.com/users/flair/295869.png?theme=clean' | head
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=86400
Content-Type: image/png
Expires: Wed, 27 Jun 2012 12:54:04 GMT
Last-Modified: Sat, 28 Apr 2012 12:54:04 GMT
Date: Sat, 28 Apr 2012 13:32:05 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Length: 12207

�PNG
```

This is the full image (but with white background).

I also tried a traceroute, but I suppose this doesn't really help, as it likely only goes to your loadbalancer:

```
$ traceroute stackexchange.com
traceroute to stackexchange.com (64.34.119.12), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1-4  [snipped]
 5  194.25.210.46 (194.25.210.46)  80.883 ms  83.581 ms  86.781 ms
 6  vl-3205-ve-136.ebr2.Berlin1.Level3.net (4.69.161.13)  89.956 ms  54.398 ms  56.952 ms
 7  4.69.200.161 (4.69.200.161)  57.369 ms 4.69.200.165 (4.69.200.165)  60.358 ms 4.69.200.161 (4.69.200.161)  62.761 ms
 8  ae-48-48.ebr1.Amsterdam1.Level3.net (4.69.143.209)  67.968 ms ae-47-47.ebr1.Amsterdam1.Level3.net (4.69.143.205)  70.616 ms  73.254 ms
 9  ae-1-100.ebr2.Amsterdam1.Level3.net (4.69.141.170)  77.259 ms  79.626 ms  82.550 ms
10  ae-45-45.ebr2.London1.Level3.net (4.69.143.70)  91.989 ms  94.837 ms ae-47-47.ebr2.London1.Level3.net (4.69.143.78)  99.295 ms
11  ae-41-41.ebr1.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.137.66)  168.292 ms ae-44-44.ebr1.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.137.78)  175.474 ms ae-42-42.ebr1.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.137.70)  178.165 ms
12  ae-91-91.csw4.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.134.78)  146.553 ms ae-71-71.csw2.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.134.70)  135.027 ms ae-81-81.csw3.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.134.74)  139.881 ms
13  ae-3-80.edge1.NewYork1.Level3.net (4.69.155.142)  138.495 ms  141.074 ms  143.775 ms
14  * * *
15  gig2-0.nyc-gsr-b.peer1.net (216.187.123.5)  155.850 ms  158.201 ms  161.404 ms
16  64.34.60.18 (64.34.60.18)  164.375 ms  166.790 ms  169.551 ms
17  * * *
18  * * *
```

The same difference also occurs from a second computer (behind the same NAT), where I'm not logged in, and from one of my university's SSH server's - also in Berlin, but not linked via Level3 to the US:

```
traceroute to stackexchange.com (64.34.119.12), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets using UDP
 1-4  [snipped]
 5  zr-pot1-te0-0-0-3.x-win.dfn.de (188.1.144.30)  2.368 ms   2.007 ms   2.134 ms
 6  zr-fra1-te0-7-0-0.x-win.dfn.de (188.1.145.205)  19.659 ms   19.617 ms   19.503 ms
 7  kr-0tisca.x-win.dfn.de (188.1.232.114)  15.020 ms   15.142 ms   15.030 ms
 8  xe-7-2-0.nyc20.ip4.tinet.net (89.149.183.26)  104.543 ms   104.267 ms   104.337 ms
 9  peer1-gw.ip4.tinet.net (77.67.70.194)  104.320 ms   104.186 ms   104.246 ms
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  64.34.60.18 (64.34.60.18)  99.147 ms   99.319 ms   99.001 ms
13  * * *
14  * * *
```

**Update:** Now, one day later (2012-04-29, 9:47) it looks right again for me. Maybe this is because of my additional badge :-)

Comment: Entering `http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/295869.png` in the address bar of Safari gives the image shown in the first screenshot.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Interestingly, it seems to work for your flair, showing multiple accounts here: http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/79630.png

Comment: Strange. I get the correct image from here (Paraguay) and my servers in US and NL.

Comment: [bug that has been already reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129520/what-happened-to-my-flair)?

Comment: @gnat: Yes, you are right. Looks like the same problem.

Comment: One more observation: If I append `?theme=clean` (but not `?theme=default`), I get a good image, showing all my accounts, too. I'm using this now for printing ...